# Closing dropdown in react by clicking outside of it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

I am using a react dropdown component to create a dropdown. I am using a semantic library and customizing the dropdown:

[image: dropdown image description here]

This dropdown appears when I click on "Add Task" and I want to close it on clicking outside or anywhere else.

My dropdown is something like this:

`<Dropdown{...taskDropdownList}/>`

How can I do that?

Comment: can you post which library this belongs to? AFAIK this is not a vanilla react component

Answer (score 0):

your question lacks the necessary details so i took my best guess as to what library you're using. this works as expected "onBlur" without any special logic.

```
import "./styles.css";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Drop down example</h1>
      <Dropdown options={["matt", "alex"]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wozniak-fn0do?file=/src/App.js